# How to run a specific sql query for every row in the table?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

So I have two tables in my Database and they both look something like this:

Communication: (Calls made)

```
Timestamp            FromIDNumber ToIDNumber GeneralLocation 
2012-03-02 09:02:30  878          674        Grasslands 
2012-03-02 11:30:01  456          213        Tundra 
2012-03-02 07:02:12  789          654        Mountains
```

Movement:

```
Timestamp            IDNumber Type        X   Y  
2012-03-02 11:02:30  379      pedestrian  32  46
2012-03-01 12:32:41  654      pedestrian  54  56
2012-03-02 07:02:16  789      pedestrian  39  52
```

What I want to do is to find the closest Movement timestamp to a given Communication timestamp. Basically, I want to find where a person might have been when he/she made a call.

Currently, I did this:

```
SELECT 
      movement.timestamp,
      movement.x,
      movement.y 
 FROM movement
WHERE (movement.IDNumber=789 AND movement.timestamp>='2012-03-02 07:02:12')
ORDER BY movement.timestamp LIMIT 1;
```

and the output would be:

```
timestamp            x   y 
2012-03-02 07:02:12  39  52
```

Where I set the `IDNumber` and `timestamp` to the `FromIDNumber` of the caller, and `timestamp` they made the call. So, that'll find the probable location of one caller.

In this case, `789` made a call at `07:02:12`, and there's movement data for him at `07:02:16` which says his position is at `(39,52)`. So that would show up as his probable location, seeing as it's only 4 seconds later.

But how do I run that specific query for every single call in the Communication table without having to fill each in one by hand?

For example then, instead of only being calculated for 1 call, the location would be calculated for all the rows of the communication table like:

```
timestamp            x   y 
2012-03-02 07:02:12  39  52
2012-03-02 03:15:14  23  34
2012-03-02 05:06:07  34  55
2012-03-02 02:41:21  12  56
...
```

and so on.

I tried using something with [java.sql](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/package-summary.html) but things got a bit complicated, and I wondered if there was an easier way. How would I solve this issue?

The problem is that I just started learning SQL so I'm not really sure what to do here at all. I looked at some other SO posts, but they were all for sql-server, and I wasn't really able to understand. Any help would be greatly appreciated thank you!

Comment: Are you open to scripting in PHP?  Someone might be able to give you a pure mySQL solution, but I would typically write a quick script for this.

Comment: Can you please provide the desired result (with explanation) based on your posted sample data. You might need to update your sample data as well.

Comment: @steveklein I am open to it, but it's just that since I've never done anything with PHP at all, I was hoping that I could look to other things first.

Comment: @steveklein: There's absolutely no reason this can't be done in pure SQL, and introduction of PHP is a (nasty) complication.

Comment: Sorry I am tired - I saw `phpmyadmin` and read `php`.  Really any scripting language will do - doesn't need to be `PHP`.  Assuming the `communications` table is not huge, you could just pull what you need into memory and the loop through it, generating that `select` for each row.

Comment: @PM77-1 I just changed it to a better example!

Comment: @steveklein: Again, there's no need for any scripting language. A sub-select and JOIN would do. I'm not familiar enough with MySQL syntax to write an answer, but it could easily be accomplished with SQL Server, and I'm certain a MySQL solution is possible as well. There's no need to introduce another language into this at all, and no need for a loop of any sort.

Comment: @steveklein That's what I tried to do before actually... and unfortunately, the Communications table is a bit large, with a couple million entries. I'm now trying to find something simpler with just SQL

Comment: @KenWhite Thanks for clarifying issues! So I would just need to use sub-select and join for this in MySQL?

Comment: Yes. You can use an INNER JOIN on `movement.IDNumber` and `communication.FromIDNumber`, and a sub-select on the timestamp to find the closest match. As I said, I'm not familiar enough with MySQL syntax (particularly when it relates to the date/time functionality) to write an answer.

Comment: @KenWhite Hmmm okay I'll keep that in mind, and try something with that thanks!!

Comment: Posted. Please give it a try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one:

```
SELECT c.FromIDNumber, m.Timestamp, m.X, m.Y
FROM Communication c
JOIN Movement m ON c.FromIDNumber = m.IDNumber
WHERE m.TimeStamp = (SELECT MIN(mm.Timestamp)
                     FROM Movement mm
                     WHERE mm.TimeStamp >= c.TimeStamp)
```

You can use [this **SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1c4ff/7) to test with different data combinations.

Comment: Unfortunately, the server query is taking forever so I can't check this solution on the actual dataset, but I played around on the SQL Fiddle and it seemed to work great, thank you so much!!

Comment: Do you have indexes on IDs and Timestamps in both tables?

Comment: I don't think so, why?

Comment: I just looked that up thank you, I had no idea about indexing, but I think that would help a lot.... seeing as the server query is still ongoing. I'll check it out!

Comment: Also check [`EXPLAIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html) to make sure that the server does use your new indexes.

Comment: Thanks! might have missed that