# Find the closest timestamp SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, timestamp

I have two tables that look like this:

Communication: (Calls made)

```
Timestamp            FromIDNumber ToIDNumber GeneralLocation 
2012-03-02 09:02:30  878          674        Grasslands 
2012-03-02 11:30:01  456          213        Tundra 
2012-03-02 07:02:12  789          654        Mountains
```

Movement:

```
Timestamp            IDNumber Type        X   Y  
2012-03-02 11:02:30  379      pedestrian  32  46
2012-03-01 12:32:41  654      pedestrian  54  56
2012-03-02 07:02:16  789      pedestrian  39  52
```

And the following query:

```
SELECT c.FromIDNumber, m.Timestamp, m.X, m.Y
FROM Communication c
JOIN Movement m ON c.FromIDNumber = m.IDNumber
WHERE m.TimeStamp = (SELECT MIN(mm.Timestamp)
                 FROM Movement mm
                 WHERE mm.TimeStamp >= c.TimeStamp)
```

Basically, it goes through every row of `Commmunication` and finds the location of a call made by finding the closest movement timestamp for a given communication timestamp. (Here's the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a25f5/1)).

The problem for me is that it only returns the closest `movement timestamp` that is *after* a certain `communication timestamp`. For example, given this simple example:

```
 Communication Time: 
 1:10 pm 

 Movement Data: 
 1:09 pm   (100,100)
 1:15 pm   (200,200)
```

The query will return the `1:15pm (200,200)`, even though the closest `timestamp` is the 1:09 pm. How would I write an sql query to find the closest time? I found a kinda similar [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17125844/closest-timestamp-from-a-table) for `sql-server`, but how would I do this in `MySQL`?

I just don't have much experience in SQL, so help would be greatly appreciated thanks!!!

Comment: I knew it [sounded familiar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30408106/how-to-run-a-specific-sql-query-for-every-row-in-the-table).

Comment: @PM77-1 Indeed... unfortunately I'm still stuck

Comment: Take the difference of all the timestamps with your timestamp of interest and look for the minimum absolute value.

Comment: What @ssnobody said and specifically, `ABS(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp1)-UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp2))`.

Comment: Oh I see.. thanks!! I think that'll get me started, and I can probably figure it out from there

Comment: @Turophile - It seems that [TIMESTAMPDIFF()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) will give a more compact solution.

Comment: Thanks, @PM77-1, I missed that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want this version:

```
SELECT c.FromIDNumber, m.Timestamp, m.X, m.Y
FROM Communication c
JOIN Movement m ON c.FromIDNumber = m.IDNumber
WHERE m.TimeStamp = (SELECT mm.Timestamp
                     FROM Movement mm
                     ORDER BY abs(mm.TimeStamp - c.TimeStamp)
                     LIMIT 1
                    );
```

You may need to use `timestampdiff()` instead of `-` depending on the types of the column.

Comment: Thanks that works really well!! Just wondering, I keep on getting " `BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range in  '(`DBName.mm.timestamp - DBName.c.timestamp)' ` "  Do you know the reason for this?

Comment: @ocean800 . . . That happens when you have negative values.  You can rewrite it as `order by (greatest(mm.TimeStamp, c.TimeStamp) - least(mm.TimeStamp, c.TimeStamp))`.

Comment: Oh, I see.. in the end, I just used timestampdiff(), but thanks!!